# Flag moderator dialog confusion

Tags: support, flags

It's a bit confusing.

After opening the dialog, "it needs ♦ moderator attention", is selected by default.

Try clicking "FLAG QUESTION" button. Nothing happens.

You actually have to click, "other", and then enter some text before you can flag the question.

Comment: You simply have to choose a reason ("very low quality" also works)

Comment: @Sklivvz This question could've stayed on Skeptics meta. :)

Comment: @AnnaLear why? This has got nothing to do with Skeptics. It also happens [here](https://skitch.com/sklivvz/8x3rj/flag-moderator-dialog-confusion-meta-stack-overflow)

Comment: @Sklivvz The main idea being, a regular user shouldn't/doesn't need to worry about picking the right place to post issues or follow them through in a migration. So to avoid adding confusion for most users, we monitor child metas as well and address requests like this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

On Skeptics there isn't a visual indication of when the "Flag Question" button is disabled.

[image: screenshot]

[image: screenshot]

While it is by design that you need to report a reason to flag, it would help if it is possible to notice when the button is disabled, and when it is enabled, in the same way it happens on Stack Overflow.

[image: screenshot]

[image: screenshot]

As it is on Skeptics, it seems you are allowed to click on the button, even when you don't enter any reason for flagging.

Comment: Incorrect, this is not Skeptics specific, it's *reputation specific*! See [here](https://skitch.com/sklivvz/8x3rj/flag-moderator-dialog-confusion-meta-stack-overflow) for a screenshot of how *I* see flagging here (and I don't see the issue on Skeptics...) ;-)

Answer (score 8):

This is by-design.

"it needs ♦ moderator attention" is just a category, "other" is subcategory. It is always better (for moderators) to have a description about *what is actually wrong* with that question. That's why it's disabled by default

Comment: Indeed, the extra time required help to get more people to actually explain what's wrong with the post. :)

Comment: I can see Dave's confusion though. Saying it is "just a category" ignores that there is no other category, so the outer radio button serves no purpose but to distract from the inner radio buttons (incorrectly suggesting there are three choices to select between.)

Comment: @Odd: It makes more sense if you try flagging an answer. There is another option available in the same sub-category: "not an answer".

Comment: @TheEstablishment: thank you. That gives context as to how this confusion came about. However, it isn't an excuse to leave it this way. The user shouldn't be required to understand about how this code is being re-used.